# R Error: parameters without starting value

Tags: r, non-linear-regression

Non linear real world data, n=2,600

```
SAMPLE 
X values    71.33   74.98   80  85.35   90.03
Y values    119.17  107.73  99.72   75  54.59
```

I manually graphed a formula for a starting point,

```
formula:  y = b/x^2+a
manual:   y = 800000/x^2-39.5
sum of residuals = 185
correlation forecast to actual =0.79
```

Using the nls formula in R, I get an error message:

```
a_start = -39.5
b_start = 800000
m<-nls(y~b/(x^2)+a, start=list(a=a_start,b=b_start))

Error in nls(y~ b/(x^2) + a, start = list(a = a_start, b = b_start)) : 
parameters without starting value in 'data': y, x
```

Not sure what I am missing here.

Answer (score 7):

I can reproduce your error. `nls` function is missing the argument `data` in it.

```
 m<-nls(y ~ b/(x^2)+a, start=list(a=a_start, b=b_start))
 # Error in nls(y ~ b/(x^2) + a, start = list(a = a_start, b = b_start)) : 
 # parameters without starting value in 'data': y, x
```

Now data `df` is created and passed into nls function. Make sure, the insulated expression in `I()` is the intended one.

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(71.33,   74.98 ,  80 , 85.35  , 90.03),
                 y = c(119.17,  107.73 , 99.72 ,  75,  54.59))
a_start <- -39.5
b_start <- 800000
m <- nls(y ~ I(b/(x^2+a)), data = df, start=list(a=a_start, b=b_start)) 
summary(m)

# Formula: y ~ I(b/(x^2 + a))
# 
# Parameters:
#   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
# a  -1743.2      872.5  -1.998   0.1396  
# b 412486.2    89981.4   4.584   0.0195 *
#   ---
#   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Residual standard error: 9.103 on 3 degrees of freedom
# 
# Number of iterations to convergence: 6 
# Achieved convergence tolerance: 4.371e-06
```

Read the formula man page for insulated expression.

```
?formula
```

The man page of `formula` says that

> The ^ operator indicates crossing to the specified degree. For example
>   (a+b+c)^2 is identical to (a+b+c)*(a+b+c) which in turn expands to a
>   formula containing the main effects for a, b and c together with their
>   second-order interactions

Also it suggests using `I()` to prevent ambiguity between formula operators and arithmetic operators.

Here is the another quote from formula man page

> avoid this confusion, the function I() can be used to bracket those
>   portions of a model formula where the operators are used in their
>   arithmetic sense. For example, in the formula y ~ a + I(b+c), the term
>   b+c is to be interpreted as the sum of b and c.

Also this man page is worth reading

```
 ?AsIs
```

> In function formula. There it is used to inhibit the interpretation of
>   operators such as "+", "-", "*" and "^" as formula operators, so they
>   are used as arithmetical operators. This is interpreted as a symbol by
>   terms.formula.

Comment: yes, perfectly, and the changes worked!  I am not a programmer by trade, so I find some of the R documentation difficult to read, or here to look to find certain syntax solutions. . .